# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Could not find anywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

The conversion from py2 to py3 gave this error and could not find anywhere. In line 242 is the error. Below the code that calls it.

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "CHAMADA_KECCAK.py", line 51, in <module> f = g.funcao()

  File "CHAMADA_KECCAK.py", line 46, in funcao  y = x.sha3_256(t).digest()

  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\UENF\11 PERIODO\MONOGRAFIA ARTHUR EM ANDAMENTO\python_sha3.py", line 242, in digest

   M = _build_message_pair(self.buffered_data.decode('hex'))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Code: CHAMADA_KECCAK.py

```
import python_sha3

class principal:
    def funcao(self):

        t = 'arthurrieofkmdslmvdsmveribmfkdbdfmbero'
        x = python_sha3
        y = x.sha3_256(t).digest()
        return y
        print ("\nO hash Keccak-256 do texto: \n %s \nEh:\n %s"%(t , y))

g = principal()
f = g.funcao()
```

Code: python_sha3.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math

def sha3_256(data=None):
  return Keccak(c=512, r=1088, n=256, data=data)


class KeccakError(Exception):
  #Classe de erro personalizada usada na implementacao do Keccak

  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def __str__(self):
    return repr(self.value)


class Keccak:
  def __init__(self, r, c, n, data=None):
    # Inicialize as constantes usadas em todo o Keccak
    # taxa de bits
    self.r = r
    # capacidade
    self.c = c
    # tamanho da saida
    self.n = n

    self.b = r + c
    # b = 25*w
    self.w = self.b // 25
    # 2**l = w
    self.l = int(math.log(self.w, 2))

    self.n_r = 12 + 2 * self.l

    self.block_size = r
    self.digest_size = n

    # Inicialize o estado da esponja
    # O estado eh composto por 25 palavras, cada palavra sendo w bits.
    self.S =[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    # Uma sequencia de hexchars, em que cada caractere representa 4 bits.
    self.buffered_data = ""

    # Armazene o resumo calculado.
    # Apenas aplicaremos preenchimento e recalcularemos o hash se ele for modificado.
    self.last_digest = None

    if data:
      self.update(data)

  # Constantes

  # # Constantes redondas
  RC = [0x0000000000000001,
        0x0000000000008082,
        0x800000000000808A,
        0x8000000080008000,
        0x000000000000808B,
        0x0000000080000001,
        0x8000000080008081,
        0x8000000000008009,
        0x000000000000008A,
        0x0000000000000088,
        0x0000000080008009,
        0x000000008000000A,
        0x000000008000808B,
        0x800000000000008B,
        0x8000000000008089,
        0x8000000000008003,
        0x8000000000008002,
        0x8000000000000080,
        0x000000000000800A,
        0x800000008000000A,
        0x8000000080008081,
        0x8000000000008080,
        0x0000000080000001,
        0x8000000080008008]

  ## Deslocamentos de rotacao
  r = [[0,  36,   3,  41,  18],
       [1,  44,  10,  45,   2],
       [62,  6,  43,  15,  61],
       [28, 55,  25,  21,  56],
       [27, 20,  39,   8,  14]]

  @staticmethod
  def Round(A, RCfixed, w):
    """Execute uma rodada de calculo conforme definido na permutacao Keccak-f
    A: estado atual (matriz 5x5)
    RCfixed: valor da constante arredondada a ser usada (inteiro)"""

    #Inicializacao de variaveis temporarias

    B = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    C = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    D = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    #Etapa Theta
    for x in range(5):
      C[x] = A[x][0] ^ A[x][1] ^ A[x][2] ^ A[x][3] ^ A[x][4]

    for x in range(5):
      D[x] = C[(x - 1) % 5] ^ _rot(C[(x + 1) % 5], 1, w)

    for x in range(5):
      for y in range(5):
        A[x][y] = A[x][y] ^ D[x]

    #Etapa Rho e Pi
    for x in range(5):
      for y in range(5):
        B[y][(2 * x + 3 * y) % 5] = _rot(A[x][y], Keccak.r[x][y], w)

    #Etapa Chi
    for x in range(5):
      for y in range(5):
        A[x][y] = B[x][y] ^ ((~B[(x + 1) % 5][y]) & B[(x + 2) % 5][y])

    #Etapa Iota
    A[0][0] = A[0][0] ^ RCfixed
    return A

  @staticmethod
  def KeccakF(A, n_r, w):
    """Execute a funcao Keccak-f no estado A
    A: matriz 5x5 contendo o estado, em que cada entrada eh uma sequencia de hexchars com 'w' bits de comprimento
    n_r: numero de rodadas
    w: tamanho da palavra
    """

    for i in xrange(n_r):
      A = Keccak.Round(A, Keccak.RC[i] % (1 << w), w)
#    print (A)
    return A

  ### Regra de preenchimento
  @staticmethod
  def pad10star1(M, n):
    """PAD M com a regra de preenchimento pad10 * 1 para atingir um comprimento multiplo de r bits
    M: par de mensagens (comprimento em bits, sequencia de caracteres hexadecimais ('9AFC ...')
    n: comprimento em bits (deve ser multiplo de 8)
    Exemplo: pad10star1 ([60, 'BA594E0FB9EBBD30'], 8) retorna 'BA594E0FB9EBBD93'
    """

    [my_string_length, my_string] = M

    # Verifique o parametro n
    if n % 8 != 0:
      raise KeccakError.KeccakError("n deve ser um multiplo de 8")

    # Verifique o comprimento da string fornecida
    if len(my_string) % 2 != 0:
      #Pad com um '0' para atingir o comprimento correto (nao sei codificacao de vetores de teste)
      my_string += '0'
    if my_string_length > (len(my_string) // 2 * 8):
      raise KeccakError.KeccakError("A cadeia eh muito curta para conter o numero de bits anunciados")

    nr_bytes_filled = my_string_length // 8
    nbr_bits_filled = my_string_length % 8
    l = my_string_length % n
    if ((n - 8) <= l <= (n - 2)):
      if (nbr_bits_filled == 0):
        my_byte = 0
      else:
        my_byte = int(my_string[nr_bytes_filled * 2:nr_bytes_filled * 2 + 2], 16)
      my_byte = (my_byte >> (8 - nbr_bits_filled))
      my_byte = my_byte + 2 ** (nbr_bits_filled) + 2 ** 7
      my_byte = "%02X" % my_byte
      my_string = my_string[0:nr_bytes_filled * 2] + my_byte
    else:
      if (nbr_bits_filled == 0):
        my_byte = 0
      else:
        my_byte = int(my_string[nr_bytes_filled * 2:nr_bytes_filled * 2 + 2], 16)
      my_byte = (my_byte >> (8 - nbr_bits_filled))
      my_byte = my_byte + 2 ** (nbr_bits_filled)
      my_byte = "%02X" % my_byte
      my_string = my_string[0:nr_bytes_filled * 2] + my_byte
      while((8 * len(my_string) // 2) % n < (n - 8)):
        my_string = my_string + '00'
      my_string = my_string + '80'

#    print (my_string)
    return my_string

  def update(self, arg):
    """Atualize o objeto hash com a string arg. Chamadas repetidas sao equivalentes a 
    uma unica chamada com a concatenacao de todos os argumentos: m.update (a); 
    m.update (b) eh equivalente a m.update (a + b). arg eh um bytestring normal. 
    """
    self.last_digest = None
    # Converta os dados em um formato viavel e adicione-os ao buffer
    self.buffered_data += arg.encode("utf-8").hex()

    # Absorver todos os blocos que pudermos:
    if len(self.buffered_data) * 4 >= self.r:
      extra_bits = len(self.buffered_data) * 4 % self.r

      # Um ajuste exato!
      if extra_bits == 0:
        P = self.buffered_data
        self.buffered_data = ""
      else:
        # Fatie-o nos primeiros bits r * a, para alguma constante a> = 1, e o restante total-r * a bits.
        P = self.buffered_data[:-extra_bits // 4]
        self.buffered_data = self.buffered_data[-extra_bits // 4:]

      #Fase de absorcao
      for i in xrange((len(P) * 8 // 2) // self.r):
        to_convert = P[i * (2 * self.r // 8):(i + 1) * (2 * self.r // 8)] + '00' * (self.c // 8)
        P_i = _convertStrToTable(to_convert, self.w, self.b)

        # Primeiro aplique o XOR ao estado + bloco
        for y in xrange(5):
          for x in xrange(5):
            self.S[x][y] = self.S[x][y] ^ P_i[x][y]
        # Em seguida, aplique a permutacao do bloco, Keccak-F
        self.S = Keccak.KeccakF(self.S, self.n_r, self.w)

  def digest(self):
    """Retorne o resumo das strings passadas para o metodo update () ate o momento.
    Esta eh uma sequencia de bytes digest_size que pode conter dados nao ASCII
    caracteres, incluindo bytes nulos."""

    if self.last_digest:
      return self.last_digest

    # AVISO FEIO
    # Lidar com conversoes bytestring / hexstring
    M = _build_message_pair(self.buffered_data.decode('hex'))

    # Primeiro termine o preenchimento e force a atualizacao final:
    self.buffered_data = Keccak.pad10star1(M, self.r)
    self.update('')
    # AVISO FEIO terminado

    assert len(self.buffered_data) == 0, "Por que existem dados restantes no buffer? %s com comprimento %d" % (self.buffered_data, len(self.buffered_data) * 4)

    # Aperto o tempo!
    Z = ''
    outputLength = self.n
    while outputLength > 0:
      string = _convertTableToStr(self.S, self.w)
      # Leia os primeiros bits 'r' do estado
      Z = Z + string[:self.r * 2 // 8]
      outputLength -= self.r
      if outputLength > 0:
        S = KeccakF(S, verbose)

    self.last_digest = Z[:2 * self.n // 8]
    return self.last_digest

  def hexdigest(self):
    """Como digest(), exceto que o resumo eh retornado como uma sequencia de digitos hexadecimais.
    Isso pode ser usado para trocar o valor com seguranca em e-mail ou outros
    ambientes nao binarios."""
    return self.digest().encode('hex')

  def copy(self):
    # Inicialize primeiro o que pode ser feito normalmente
    duplicate = Keccak(c=self.c, r=self.r, n=self.n)
    # Entao copie sobre o estado.
    for i in xrange(5):
      for j in xrange(5):
        duplicate.S[i][j] = self.S[i][j]
    # e quaisquer outros dados armazenados
    duplicate.buffered_data = self.buffered_data
    duplicate.last_digest = self.last_digest
    return duplicate



## Funcoes genericas do utilitario

def _build_message_pair(data):
  hex_data = data.encode('hex')
  size = len(hex_data) * 4
  return (size, hex_data)


def _rot(x, shift_amount, length):
  """Gire x shift_amount bits para a esquerda, considerando o \
  cadeia de bits tem comprimento bits"""

  shift_amount = shift_amount % length
  return ((x >> (length - shift_amount)) + (x << shift_amount)) % (1 << length)

### Funcoes de conversao String <-> Tabela (e vice-versa)


def _fromHexStringToLane(string):
  """Converta uma cadeia de bytes gravada em hexadecimal em um valor de faixa"""

  #Verifique se a string possui um numero par de caracteres, ou seja, um numero inteiro de bytes
  if len(string) % 2 != 0:
    raise KeccakError.KeccakError("A cadeia fornecida nao termina com um byte completo")

  #Realize a conversao
  temp = ''
  nrBytes = len(string) // 2
  for i in xrange(nrBytes):
    offset = (nrBytes - i - 1) * 2
    temp += string[offset:offset + 2]
  return int(temp, 16)


def _fromLaneToHexString(lane, w):
  """Converta um valor de pista em uma cadeia de bytes gravada em hexadecimal"""

  laneHexBE = (("%%0%dX" % (w // 4)) % lane)
  #Realize a conversao
  temp = ''
  nrBytes = len(laneHexBE) // 2
  for i in xrange(nrBytes):
    offset = (nrBytes - i - 1) * 2
    temp += laneHexBE[offset:offset + 2]
  return temp.upper()


def _convertStrToTable(string, w, b):
  """Converta uma sequencia de caracteres hexadecimais em sua representacao matricial 5x5
  string: sequencia de bytes de bytes codificados em hexadecimal (por exemplo, '9A2C ...')"""

  # Verifique se os parametros de entrada sao esperados
  if w % 8 != 0:
    raise KeccakError("w nao eh multiplo de 8")

  # Cada caractere na sequencia representa 4 bits.
  # A string deve ter exatamente bits 'b'.
  if len(string) * 4 != b:
    raise KeccakError.KeccakError("a string nao pode ser dividida em 25 blocos de w bits \
    ou seja, a string deve ter exatamente b bits")

  #Converter
  output = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

  bits_per_char = 2 * w // 8
  for x in xrange(5):
    for y in xrange(5):
      # Cada entrada tera b / 25 = w bits.
      offset = (5 * y + x) * bits_per_char
      # Cada entrada tera b / 25 = w bits.
      hexstring = string[offset:offset + bits_per_char]
      output[x][y] = _fromHexStringToLane(hexstring)
  return output


def _convertTableToStr(table, w):
  """Converta uma representacao de matriz 5x5 na sua representacao de cadeia"""

  #Verifique o formato de entrada
  if w % 8 != 0:
    raise KeccakError.KeccakError("w nao eh multiplo de 8")
  if (len(table) != 5) or any(len(row) != 5 for row in table):
    raise KeccakError.KeccakError("a tabela deve ser 5x5")

  #Converter
  output = [''] * 25
  for x in xrange(5):
    for y in xrange(5):
      output[5 * y + x] = _fromLaneToHexString(table[x][y], w)
  output = ''.join(output).upper()
  return output
```

Comment: `str.decode` is a Python 2 function but not in Python 3. Since this is in an external file, you probably either forgot to update that library, or you included the same – older – version for your new project, hoping it didn't matter. (It does.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str` is already decoded and you are trying to decode it, which is already decoded. but if you really want to decode it, you should encode it, and then decode it again. i don't recommend it.

i recommend you to use `binascii`. note that the input string should be a byte-like object.

```
import binascii
a = b'hello'
# encoding string to equivalent hex representation
b=binascii.hexlify(a)
print(b)
>>> b'68656c6c6f'
# decoding b
c=binascii.unhexlify(b)
print(c)
>>> b'hello'
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\UENF\11 PERIODO\MONOGRAFIA ARTHUR EM ANDAMENTO\python_sha3.py", line 207, in update
    self.buffered_data += binascii.b2a_hex(b'arg')
TypeError: must be str, not bytes ----- Now you're giving this error

Comment: that's why you've defined `buffered_data` as `str` ! it should be byte like object like `self.buffered_data = b""`